# Javascript empty loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I saw some code like this:

```
while(ajaxCallInProgress)
        {
        }
        ajaxCallInProgress = true;
```

What is the use of this empty loop in javascript? What its does ? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if `ajaxCallInProgress` is a truthy expression, this will be an infinity-loop (and therefore, will freeze the interpreter forever).

It makes sense in a lot of places to do something, while a specific condition is true, but in all of those cases, the condition which is checked must set to a **falsy** value at some point **within** the loop body.

Since ECMA-/Javascript doesn't support multiple threads (I Just ignore web-workers here), there is no way this variable could get modified somewhere else.

**Conclusion**:

whereever you saw this code you either didn't copy & paste it completely or the author of this code didn't really know what he is doing.

Comment: @ThomBlake: I just hope you didn't downvote here on your opinion, because you are wrong sir. Events have nothing to do with the described problen. The Event-loop needs to make sure that there is no blocking process/operation to work properly. An infinite loop will lock down the browsers UI thread (which is also used to execute javascript). There will no events get fired as long as the loop runs(and that is, forever).

Comment: @jAndy Indeed I was incorrect.  And it's not browser-dependent - it blocks in node as well.

Comment: @jAndy so the empty while loop i think will not ever complete because as you say it is one threaded application (though it is so misleading I think) however it does have "virtual threads" where it switches between work. But as a thread switches based on units of time, the javascript environment appears to switch based upon units of execution and the entire while loop (from start to finish) seems to be a basic unit here. So it will not switch to handle asynchronous events until it finishes. So no other events can change the value to end the while loop. It seems to me that the often suggesteed..

Comment: ... solution to sleep or wait wont work either because those are units to. setTimeout(1000) alone wouldnt work, you need to pass a recursive function to get the effect of an empty while loop which waits for an event.

Answer (score 2):

It loops endlessly until `ajaxCallinProgress` becomes `false`. While it loops it's eating as much CPU as one thread can.

I think this is a very bad example of performing a blocking operation, a better way to handle something that is asynchronous would be with events.

Hope this helped.

Comment: ajaxCallInPrgress will never become false, as the loop will block any other code from running

Comment: @Zacahary what if a `XMLHttpRequest` was made, it would still be able to receive that event. Right?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's locking code to prevent more than one AJAX call happening at once. Basically, if ajaxCallInProgress is true then it waits until it's been set to false by a completion callback somewhere and then sets it to true itself so it can make its own call. Not an ideal approach, queueing the calls would make more sense, but that's what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

The code is creating a spinlock. This code will spin around and around doing nothing while it waits for an event handler to change the value of ajaxCallInProgress. Presumably an Ajax request has been sent off to a server and this code is waiting for the response to come back and for the event handler waiting for that response to change the value of ajaxCallInProgress, after which this code will continue on.

Answer (score 0):

if ajaxCallInProgress is true then it will do an infinite loop. Javascript is single threaded so the value will never change inside the loop. You want to use a callback function to know when the ajax call is finished.

What you want is something like this:

$.get('url', {params: true}, function success (data){ 
 /*this will run when the ajax call finishes */});

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to wait the response of an ajax call. Basically, this loop waits until the global variable `ajaxCallInProgress` is set to `false` by another JavaScript function.

So when the response is received, the corresponding JavaScript function will set `ajaxCallInProgress = false;`, and your loop will stop.

Answer (score 0):

If the "ajaxCallInProgress" is true at the beginning and the script isn't run async it would hang your browser.

If it's run async it would consume alot of CPU but the browser wouldn't hang..  hard to tell anything more from that code.

Comment: Javascript doesn't run async. It will block and hang the browser.